# Creating new attribute using addAttribute() in installation scripts

Tags: attributes, extensions, install, data

I'm writing an installation script in an extension that adds some new attributes. I'm using the following. I'm following and old tutorial (http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-adding-attribute-from-mysql-setup-file/), but it's no longer up-to-date because `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup::addAttribute` does not include any of the "Frontend Properties" mapping, denoted by `// X`. Is it possible to set these properties with `addAttribute()`? If not, how should I go about installing a new attribute with frontend properties?

```
$setup->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'testatt', array(
    'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'input' => 'select',
    'type' => 'int',
    'backend' => '',    // backend_model
    'frontend' => '',   // fronted_model
    'label' => 'ATT NAME HERE',
    'class' => '',  ,
    'user_defined' => true,
    'required' => false,

    // Frontend Properties start here
    'visible' => true, // X
    'filterable' => true,    // X
```

);

On EE 1.13.

Update:
See benmarks' answer!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are using the incorrect setup class. `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup` has never had access to catalog-specific properties, which reside in the additional table (`catalog_eav_attribute`).

You either need to register `catalog/setup` as your module's setup resource or (more likely) instantiate it directly in your setup script:

```
$installer = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup', 'catalog_setup');
```

In order to understand the mapping, refer to [`Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup::_prepareValues()`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.8/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Setup.php#L43). I (*warning: self-promotion*) recently posted a detailed dive of EAV attribute configuration at http://www.webguys.de/magento/eav-attribute-setup/.

Comment: Yes, you are right. `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup` inherits from `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup` and has additional mapping that are merged in `addAttribute()`!

Answer (score 8):

you can try below one it will work for your requirement. This is the syntax of create the attribute via installer script.

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'page_layout', array(
  'type'              => 'varchar',
  'backend'           => '',
  'frontend'          => '',
  'label'             => 'Page Layout',
  'input'             => 'select',
  'class'             => '',
  'source'            => 'catalog/product_attribute_source_layout',
  'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
  'visible'           => true,
  'required'          => false,
  'user_defined'      => false,
  'default'           => '',
  'searchable'        => false,
  'filterable'        => false,
  'comparable'        => false,
  'visible_on_front'  => false,
  'unique'            => false,
  'group'             => 'Design'
));

$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: I've seen this example while I was searching for how to do this. This does not work. I don't believe that `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup` (`$this`) has  `addAttributes()` defined.

Comment: Because user_defined is false in your example, you also cannot delete this attribute in the admin.

Comment: Yes @DavidTay I agree with you

Answer (score 0):

This script will work if you add class "Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup" in your module config.xml setup block.